# PostgreSQL 14 on Win 10 with plpython3u extension aborts connection when creating a function in plpython3u

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to use Python 3 with PostgreSQL 13 or higher
I had all the well-known problems with creating the plpython3u extension. This is what I did to circumvent the issue:
Having installed PostgreSQL 14, Python 3.9 :

1. Moved python39.dll, python3.dll to the system32
2. Checked python39.dll with dependency walker. All required dll(s) are present; their locations are included in PATH
3. Created plpython3u extension.
4. Kept plpython3u as an untrusted language
5. Checked that plpython3u is one of the available languages (untrusted)
6. On postgres authority tried to create an elementary python function:
   CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer)
   RETURNS integer
   AS $$
   if a > b:
   return a
   return b
   $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
   CREATE FUNCTION

I get the following result:
SQL Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.

I had exactly the same result with PostgreSQL 13 and Python 3.7 .
I've no more ideas, Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: were you able to fix this problem?